# Update last user in dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql-server

Looking into column last_user_update in dm_db_index_usage_stats table.
I can see that even when I run

```
DELETE [table] WHERE 1=0
```

the last_user_update is being updated.
Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), the `user_updates` column is defined as:

> Number of updates by user queries. This includes Insert, Delete, and Updates representing number of operations done not the actual rows affected. For example, if you delete 1000 rows in one statement, this count increments by 1.

And `last_user_update` is defined as:

> Time of last user update.

Therefore, if you `DELETE` 0 rows or 1,000,000 rows, the values will be updated, as it related to the operation, not the rows. A `DELETE` that results in `0` rows being deleted is still a `DELETE` operation; whether the `WHERE` has something that can *never* be true (`0 = 1`) or something more "reasonable" `WHERE SomeColumn = @SomeVariable`.